# Can not figure out why the AJAX Request won't be sent

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm about to create my first Chrome extension (it's a Popup), it'll POST data to a server.
Thought it would be easy, but I get stuck.

in manifest.json I set permissions for "http://mypage[dot]com/" and also "http://mypage[dot]com/*" so that I can access the "mypage[dot]com/api" where the data has to be sent to.
And so my popup.html looks like:

```
     <!doctype html>
     <html lang="en">
       <meta charset="UTF-8">
       <title>myExtension</title>
     </head>
     <body>
       <form name="myform">
         <input type="text" name="myText" id="myText"/>
         <input type="submit" name="senden"/>
       </form>
     </body>
       <script src="jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
       <script src="popup.js"></script>
     </html>
```

And so my popup.js looks like:

```
      document.forms["myForm"].addEventListener("submit", sendRequest)
      function sendRequest() {
        var myVar= $('#mytext').val();
        var myrequest= $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'http://mypage.com/api/',
            data: {screen_name: 'myname', api_key: 'myKey', var1: myVar},
            success: function(data, textStatus){
                           alert('request successful');
                     },
            error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown){
                        alert(xhr); alert(textstatus); alert(errorThrown);
                     }
            });
       }
```

Now, when I hit the submit-button it'll give me only these three alerts, the first one says: [object Object], the second one: error and the third one is only empty.

I tried to solve this problem but I dont know where the error is. Also I read about some background.html and  content_script.js but I dont know what I have to do with them and some extensions, I found in the internet, only contain the popup.html and popup.js and they work as fine as they should do (e.g. the domai.nr-extension).

So I'd very happy about some explanations what I have to use and to do to post data correctly within a popup extension.

Answer (score 0):

first, you close the head tag but dont open it

try to give your form an id like

```
<form id="myform">
```

then i would simplify the js code like this

```
$('#myform').submit(function(){

    var myVar= $('#mytext').val();

    $.ajax({
        url: "http://mypage.com/api/", 
        type: "POST",        
        data: {screen_name: 'myname', api_key: 'myKey', var1: myVar},   
        success: function(data, textStatus){
            alert('request successful');
        },
        error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown){
            alert(xhr); alert(textstatus); alert(errorThrown);
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I edited my code as you say, but these three alerts are still shown.

Answer (score 0):

**Issue**

If you want to make a Cross-Origin ajax call, you need to [request appropriate permissions](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr.html#requesting-permission).

**Debugging**

Better way to debug variables than `alert()` is `console.log()`. To see the output of this method you need to open a console. To open a console for a popup: open a popup, right click on it and choose 'inspect element'. When Developer Tools will open, navigate to 'Console' tab. You will get much more information from `console.log(xhr)` than from `alert(xhr)`. In addition all permission warnings, invalid syntax warnings etc. are printed out on console making it easy to find a bug.

**AJAX from popup**

Sending a POST request from a popup has a one week point: when popup is closed (and it's closed  very easily - when user clicks something outside the popup) the request is canceled. And here comes the [background page](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages.html) you mentioned. Background page works in (surprise, surprise) background and can't be easily closed. Your popup should [communicate](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/extension.html#method-getBackgroundPage) with background page and ask it to make an ajax call. If you do that, background page will perform AJAX call even though popup may be already closed.

Comment: thanks for your response. So I created a new file called background.js with the code of popup.js in it. When I now see the "_generated_background_page.html" the console says, "$ is not is not defined". Do I have to use the XMLHttpRequest instead of the AJAX request to get this working or can I do this also with AJAX?
So now, where do I have to include the method "chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage()"? In the popup.html or popup.js or somewhere else?

Comment: `$ is not defined` means that you haven't included jQuery, add it to background scripts array.

Comment: For that I don't know at the moment what I've to do to include the jQuery-1.8.2.min.js. It is stored in the extensions folder but after having such troubles I'm sure this won't work like I thought. Can you say shortly how I have to handle this to include the jQuery?

Comment: You should include it in the exact same way as you included your background script. In your `manifest.json` you should have something like: `"background": { "scripts": ["jQuery-1.8.2.min.js", "background.js"] }`.

Comment: Okay, I did so but still the AJAX-request won't be sent. When I "inspect popup" (right-clicking the extension in the toolbar) the console just says nothing.

Comment: OK, you have background page and a popup. And does your popup take the data from form and send it to the background page? That's the whole point :) You need to have `doARequest(name, surname, message){ $.ajax(...)}` function on the background page and call `chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().doARequest(name, surname, message)` from a popup. I can write the whole extension for you but this way you won't learn anything. Links that I've provided in my answer should be sufficient. Also, try browsing sample extensions: http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples.html . Good luck!

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now I just had to add "$('#myForm').submit(function()" at the beginning of popup.js and it finally works!

Answer (score 0):

Check your function in http://mypage.com/api/.
test it by write simple response like that:

```
function nameOfFunciton(){
    echo "test";
}
```

If you see "request successful" alert, thus the problem exist in your code.